# $n$ is a square and a cube $a^2 = n = b^3\Rightarrow n\equiv 0,1\pmod{7}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponential-diophantine-equations

> Verify that if an integer is simultaneously a square and a cube, then it must be either of the form ${7k}$ or ${7k +1}$.

I have no idea on how to proceed.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Please don't comment just to say that you upvoted something. You've done that both on the question and the accepted answer and it adds nothing beyond the upvote. If everybody commented to say they'd upvoted, the comment system would be unusable.

Comment: (an addendum to @DavidRicherby's comment): sometimes, people will write "+1: <reason here>" if there is an exceptional case, or something important about the question/answer that they want to draw out.  This, done in *extreme* moderation, is considered acceptable, but only for special cases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $n$ is simultaneously a cube,

$$n\equiv a^3\equiv -1,0,1\pmod{7}$$

and a square

$$n\equiv t^2\equiv 0,1,4,2\pmod{7}$$

Therefore $n$ is either $7k$ or $7k+1$

Comment: You forgot "square" after "simultaneously....". Note that it can be proved without brute-force checking all remainders/classes - see my answer.

Answer (score 13):

Specialize $\, i = 2,\,j=3,\, p = 7\,$ below, $ $  using little Fermat  $ = \color{#c0d}{\mu F}$.

**Theorem**  $\bmod p\!:\ \color{#c00}{a^{\large i}} \equiv \color{#0a0}{b^{\large j}}\equiv n\not\equiv 0\Rightarrow n^{j-i}\equiv 1\ $ **if** $\ p = ij+1\,$ is prime.

**Proof** $\ \ n\not\equiv 0\Rightarrow a,b\not\equiv 0\,$ so $\,n^{j-i}\equiv\dfrac{n^{\large j}}{n^{\large i}}\equiv \dfrac{(\color{#c00}{a^{\large i}})^{\large j}}{(\color{#0a0}{b^{\large j}})^{\large i}}\equiv\dfrac{a^{\large p-1}}{b^{\large p-1}}\,\overset{\color{#c0f}{\mu F}}\equiv\, \dfrac{1}{1}.\ $ $\bf\small QED$

**Remark** $ $ We can generalize the Theorem by replacing "$p = ij\!+\!1$ is prime" $ $ by $ $ "$\phi(p)\mid ij$"

Generally $\,n^i\equiv 1\equiv n^j\Rightarrow n\equiv 1 $ when $\,(i,j)\!=\!1\,$ since then by Bezout $\,ii'\!+\!jj'\!=\!1\,$ so $\, 1 \equiv (n^i)^{i'}(n^j)^{j'}\! \equiv n^{ii'+jj'}\! \equiv n\,$ (or use $\,{\rm ord}(n)$  divides coprimes $\,i,j\,$ so must be $1,\,$ as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3573885/242)).

Comment: @Downvoter If something is not clear then please feel welcome to ask questions and I will be happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 6):

If an integer $a$ is simultaneously a square and a cube, it must be the sixth power of an integer $b$

Now as $7$ is prime either $7|b$ or $(7,b)=1$

If $7|b, 7|b^n$ for integer $n\ge1$

Else by Fermat's Little Theorem , $7|(b^{7-1}-1)$

Comment: $n=m^2=l^3$ implies $l$ divides $m$ so $m=al$ and so $m^2=a^2l^2=l^3$ implies $a^2=l$ and so $l^3=a^6$ thus $m$ is a sixth power of an integer? Is this correct justification?

Comment: @cello,  You are right

Comment: It was just a guess that $l$ divides $m$.. Could not see why.. I think it is not that difficult.. I will try one more time.. Thanks..

Comment: that is a good way to solve

Answer (score 4):

Check the integers mod $7$. Which are squares and which are cubes:

$$0^2=0^3=0$$
$$1^2=1^3=1$$
$$2^2 = 4,\qquad 2^3=8\equiv 1$$

$$3^2 = 9 \equiv 2,\quad3^3=27\equiv 6$$
$$4^2 = 16 \equiv 2,\quad 4^3= 64 \equiv 1$$
$$5^2 = 25 \equiv 4,\quad 5^3= 125 \equiv 6$$
$$6^2 = 36 \equiv 1,\quad 6^3=216\equiv 6.$$

So only $0, 1, 2$ and $4$ are squares, only $0, 1$ and $6$ are cubes (mod $7$). The ones that are both give the wanted answer.

Comment: I do not find this to be a convincing reason why squares and cubes mod 7 all follow this pattern.

Comment: If $a\equiv b$, then $a^n\equiv b^n$, you only need to check one representatives of the residue classes ($0,1,...,6$).